# SQL Query on TClientDataSet (CDS file) in Delphi XE?

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-xe

I converted a 2.8 MB XML file into a ClientDataSet in Delphi XE. The XML file changes quite frequently and I am basically building a new CDS file programmatically every time the XML changes. It's not only the content the changes, but also the actual structure.

The question is: Is it possible to use simple SQL on ClientDataSet1 to create a second ClientDataSet with a result table in memory? If the answer is yes, what are the basic mechanics? Currently I am only using TClientDataSet and TDataSource to make the database available to data-aware components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TxQuery may do what you want. It is a TDataSet descendant component that can be used to query one or more TDataSet descendant components using SQL statements. It is available at http://code.google.com/p/txquery/

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't run a SQL sentence over a [`TClientDataSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TClientDataSet) when is used as a memory dataset, because doesn't have associated a SQL provider. You best option is use  the filtering capabilities included in the TClientDataSet. For that you can use `Ranges` or `Filters` and then clone the result in a secondary TClientDataSet. for more details about filtering try this article [`Filtering ClientDataSets`](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29271)